# Raspberry Pi parallel power

Tags: power, raspberry-pi, parallel

I have wired up 4 Raspberry Pis in parallel, each being activated by its own SPST toggle. The circuit is being powered by a 5V 5A switching power supply. Each time I power on a pi after the initial, the previous active pis show a slight blip in the onboard power LED. I can not detect a voltage drop when I activate each additional pi and 5A is overkill on available current. I am not sure what will help this issue as I am very much a hobby level tinkerer. See attached schematic. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: There's a transient voltage drop when you power up each RPi. A source with better load regulation will help with that. But what is the concrete issue you're having? If only the LED blinks, but the RPIs are fine (don't reboot etc.) I wouldn't worry too much.

Comment: I have not tested too see if it is actually restarting.That need to be my next step. I know that the Pi has a lot of built in power protection so I find it hard to believe that and actual reboot is happening. Perhaps a capacitor in line after each switch.

Comment: I would put an inductor in series with each pi and a large cap parallel to all of them. That should filter out some of the switching current.

Comment: Thanks Aron, I plan to purchase a few components today and test for the solution.

Comment: Come to think about it, you also want a reverse bias diode parallel to each LED to allow the inductor to discharge safely after disconnect.